# How do I programmatically set the length of Most Recent Used files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse, I'm aware of the Preference setting for the number of recently opened files to offer:

[image: Preference]

For users of my RCP application I'd like to change the default length from 4 to 10.

I'm aware of the PreferenceManager, and can navigate to the correct node using this:

```
IPreferenceNode editorPrefs = preferenceManager.find
("/org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.Workbench/org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.Editors");
```

But, once I've found the node, I can't see how to access the specific property, in order to modify a value.

Anyone one done this before? Any tips?

Alternatively, I'm happy to do it via extension-point, but I couldn't get even this far via that mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This preference is set in the preferences for the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` plugin. You can access this using `ScopedPreferenceStore`

```
IPreferenceStore store = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, "org.eclipse.ui.workbench");
```

The key for recent files is `RECENT_FILES` so:

```
store.setValue("RECENT_FILES", value);
```

You may need to call the `save()` method to store the changes.

Comment: Aah, great.  That's better than the restricted method I found:     WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().setValue(IPreferenceConstants.RECENT_FILES, 6);

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note: it should also be possible [1] to update the preference from the .ini file.  But it didn't work for me.

[1] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=128411#c2